# Git rebase child branch to master

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following situation in a Git repository

```
   A - B [origin/master]
    \
     C [origin/X]
      \
       E - F [origin/Y]
```

I didn't realise when I started `Y`, that I had branched from `X`, I had intended to branch from `master`.

How can I rebase `Y` onto master *without* including commit `C`?

(Changes on `X` are to a file not touched by the commits on `Y`)

I'd like to end up with the following:

```
   A - B [origin/master]
    \   \
     \   E - F [origin/Y]
      \
       C [origin/X]
```

I tried `git rebase master` and it doesn't seem to have changed anything, output was :

```sh
Current branch Y is up to date.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily done like this:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master origin/X origin/Y
```

Given that you are using remote references, you will be on detached HEAD so you have to do this to push your resulting branch into origin's branch Y:

```
git push origin -f HEAD:Y
```

Answer (score 0):

As is always the case in Git there are probably lots of ways of achieving this, however the following should work:

1. On branch `Y` reset this to `master`: `git reset --hard master`.
2. Cherry-pick your commits across: `git cherry-pick C..F` (assuming `E` and `F` are the first and latest commit IDs on your branch after `C`).

Edited: As @eftshift0 pointed out I initially had the wrong commit ID's in my `git cherry-pick` statement - fixed now.

Comment: I wouldn't go this route... but if you take it, cherry-pick has to be `C..F`.

Comment: Fair, I like to live dangerously 

Comment: But of course!!!! Live outside what people call `normal`.... That's why we use git in the first place, don't we?